# Xcode 11 Swift 5 Switch button

Tags: swift, button, swift5, xcode11, uiswitch

I am creating a simple application, and if the user gets the answer correct it plays a sound and if the answer is wrong it plays another sound. I have created a SettingsViewController with a switch button. How do I make it so that when the switch is on, it keeps sound and when it’s off it disables all sound

Comment: I’m very very very new to this so like I don’t know how to do that but I really appreciate the extremely fast response

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [tutorial](https://www.dotnetperls.com/uiswitch-swift) to setup your switch button and read its value. Then when you read its value, mute/unmute the sound.

Save the value to UserDefaults

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(boolValue, forKey: "gameSound")
```

Retrieve the sound anywhere in the Application using

```
let sound = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "gameSound")
```

Comment: Where would I set the user defaults? Which view controller and in which function? And for the “gameSound” what do I replace that as?

Comment: The first line of UserDefaults should be set in the function which reads the switch button state. "gameSound" is just any unique string that enables you to access its value from the UserDefaults, you can replace it with whatever you want.

Comment: Okay thank you, and where would the second line go? Where would I call “sound” function and what would I write?

Comment: Second line goes in the other view controller where you would like to check if the sound is enabled or not.

Comment: By typing in what? Like I said I’m extremely extremely new to this and I forgot to mention I’m using AVFoundation for the sounds in Xcode, but what would I type in the second view controller, I called the new “sound@ by typing in the second line but then what

Comment: if sound == true { //play your sound }, if you are asking how to play a sound, then open another question, as this answer satisfies your question supposedly. Please mark as answer if I have answered your question

Comment: Final final question, when I turn off the switch it goes back on, that is my final question how do I keep the switch off

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211754/discussion-between-ali-zahr-and-dam-management).